# How to prevent one event handler to trigger all events

Tags: reactjs

i have event handler on multiple `map`ed div elements. when event is triggered it triggers on all `map`ed elements. I want that event to trigger only on clicked/selected element

```
    class App extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
super(props)


this.state = {
  edit: false,
  div: true,
}
 }

 componentDidMount(){

 this.props.getPortData()
 }
 handleDoubleClick = (event, index, cargo) => {

const name = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tag');
console.log(name, 'data tag value')
console.log(index, 'index')
console.log(event.target, 'event.target')
console.log(event.currentTarget, 'event.currentTarget')
const myIndex = cargo.id;
console.log(myIndex, 'my index')
// const test = cargo.index
console.log(cargo, 'mapedCargo')
if( myIndex === (index+356) ) {

 this.setState({
edit: true,
div: false,
 }  )
} 



 }
  render() {
 let dataReceived;
 const styleDiv = this.state.edit ? {display: 'none'} :{};  
 const styleInput = this.state.div ? {display: 'none'} :{display: 'block'};  
 // console.log(this.props, "item");
 if(this.props.Item.loading) {
   dataReceived = (<div  className="loading-relative"><div><h1 className="loading">Loading</h1></div><div className="lds-css ng-scope"><div className="lds-double-ring"><div></div><div></div></div></div></div>);
}else {
 const shiped = this.props.Item.data.ships;
 const cargo = this.props.Item.data.dock.cargoItems;
// console.log(shiped, "ship")
// console.log(cargo.index, "dock")

    const mapedShips = shiped.map(vasia => (
      <div key={vasia+vasia.id}>
          <div className="ships">
            <div className="value">
            <div  className="name" key={vasia.name}>Name: {vasia.name}</div>
            <div className="name" key={vasia.id}>Id: {vasia.id}</div>            
        </div>
          <div className="value">
        <div className="name" key={vasia.maxWeight}>Max Weight: {vasia.maxWeight}</div>
        <div className="name" key={vasia.maxVolume}>Max Volume: {vasia.maxVolume}</div>

        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    ))
    const mapedCargo = cargo.map((cargo, index) => (
      <div key={cargo+cargo.id}>
        <div className="cargo">
            <div className="value">
        <div className="name" key={cargo.id} ref={cargo.id} data-tag={cargo.id} style={styleDiv} onDoubleClick={(event) => {this.handleDoubleClick(event, index, cargo)}}>Cargo Id: {cargo.id}</div> 
          <div style={styleInput}>Cargo Id:
            <input id="test" type="text" defaultValue={cargo.id} />
          </div>

        <div className="name" key={cargo.weight}>Cargo weight: {cargo.weight}</div>
        <div className="name" key={cargo.volume}>Cargo volume: {cargo.volume}</div>

        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    ))



dataReceived = 
<div className="all">
<div className="testing">
  {/* <div className="ships"> */}
  {mapedShips}
  </div>
   <div className="testing"> 
  {mapedCargo}
  </div> 
</div>
 };

  return (
   <div className="App">
    {dataReceived}
   </div>
 );
}


 }
```

i know my code is a mess as i tried mulptiple solutions to make it work
[image]

Comment: Please, provide the code with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can help you better.

Comment: I think I know why the problem happens, but can't be sure. Please add the full component code in your question please. (show the states)

Comment: i added all code to the post

Comment: Just pass the id to the input and check if both the id matches, If it does then only that input box will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

In that case, your handleDoubleClick function should look like this

```
handleDoubleClick = (event, index) => {
  const newCargoState = this.state.cargo.map((cargo, idx) =>{
    if(idx == index){
      cargo = { div: false, edit: true }
    }
    return cargo
  })
 }
```

And your cargo key in the state should be an array of objects instead of single object

```
this.state = {
  cargo: [{
    div: true,
    edit: false
  },{
    div: true,
    edit: false
  }] // As many objects as the cargos you have
};
```

And finally wrap your input text and the text div with the appropriate && logic to show and hide according to the corresponding index value in the cargo key in the state

```
<div>
    {this.state.cargo.map((cargo, index) => (
      <div key={cargo+cargo.id}>
        <div className="cargo">
          <div className="value">
            {this.state.cargo[index].div && <div className="name" onDoubleClick={(event) => {this.handleDoubleClick(event, index)}}>
              Cargo Id: {cargo.id}
            </div>} 
            {this.state.cargo[index].edit && <div style={styleInput}>Cargo Id:
              <input id="test" type="text" defaultValue={cargo.id} />
            </div>}               
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: i have updated my post, what im looming for is when you click on id you get an input(i.e. picture) but at this point it turn all ids into inputs but i want that it would turn only whichever i clicked and not the rest of them

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple solution**

State

```
 state = {
        showIt: false,
        newKey: 0
      };
```

Function

```
handleDoubleClick = index => {
    this.setState({
      showIt: true,
      newKey: index
    });
  };
```

JSX

```
  <div>
        {this.state.cargo.map((cargo, index) => (
          <div key={cargo + cargo.id}>
            <div className="cargo">
              <div className="value">
                <div
                  className="name"
                  key={cargo.id}
                  ref={cargo.id}
                  data-tag={cargo.id}
                  style={styleDiv}
                  onDoubleClick={event => {
                    this.handleDoubleClick(event, index, cargo);
                  }}
                >
                  Cargo Id: {cargo.id}
                </div>
                {this.state.showIt && this.state.newKey === index ? (
                  <div style={styleInput} id={index}>
                    Cargo Id:
                    <input id="test" type="text" defaultValue={cargo.id} />
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}

                <div className="name" key={cargo.weight}>
                  Cargo weight: {cargo.weight}
                </div>
                <div className="name" key={cargo.volume}>
                  Cargo volume: {cargo.volume}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately none of the solutions above have worked for me

Comment: Can you post your eniture code in codepen of jsfiddle ? So that we can take a look at the working code